# Creación de tabla temporal

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes 
estoy creando una tabla temporal en `mysql` por medio de `phpmyadmin`
y al parecer la sintaxis esta buena, pero cuando la ejecuto no me refleja de forma gráfica la tabla me aparece algo así[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código de creación

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpFactura (numero_factura INT(10), referencia VARCHAR(10), cantidad INT(10), tipo_venta VARCHAR(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

PHPMyAdmin cierra la conexión a la base de datos cada vez que se refresca la ventana. Por lo tanto, tus tablas temporales desaparecen.

Puedes añadir tus sentencias SQL en el cuadro de texto de la consulta tras la creación de la tabla para que se ejecuten como un bloque y así hacer uso de la tabla temporal antes de que se cierre la conexión, pero no te aparecerá de forma gráfica en ningún caso. Mi propuesta es que si necesitas visualizar esa tabla, crees una tabla normal en vez de una temporal y luego la borres.